# FFMPEG drawtext with reload to 1 = sometimes crash

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, rtsp

I use FFMPEG to record an IP CAM Stream, and its work very well !
I use complex filter to write text on the video frame (draw text) with reload parameter to 1.

I have an other process, writed in vb.net, who update the text file all the second.
Sometimes FFMEPG crash, and i think its because he try to read the text file while my other process write content into the same file.

How can i do ? Can i say to FFMEPG to ignore this kind of error and continu recording ?
Thanks :-)

Comment: The recommended way is to update the text file atomically. Keep two files. One is read by ffmpeg, the 2nd is updated by your app. After update, copy the 2nd onto the 1st.

Comment: i have alredy do that, but sometimes the crash appear when i copy onto the 1st...

Answer (score 1):

File read/write operations between two processes are not "atomic", so you cannot guarantee the writer process will have finished when the reader reads the file.

In Linux, the `mv` and `rename` commands are atomic.

Have your *writer* program write to a temporary file and, when ready, rename that file to the file being read by FFMpeg.